# How to return a list of the values of all properties where the property name starts with a given prefix in JsonPath

Tags: jsonpath

I have a JSON object of the following form.

```
{
    "prefix.key1":"val",
    "prefix.key2":"val2",
    ......
    "anotherKey":"value",
    "morekeys":"value"
}
```

I need all the values for the properties where the property name starts with the string "prefix". Is this possible using JsonPath?